# Ms Access, How to get auto-value from another table

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 tables, customers data and activity. The customers data table has information like customer id, customer name, etc. What I want is when I input the customer ID in activity table, the customer name fill itself automatically, How can i do that? Thank you.

Comment: I just finished working on something like this. How are you inputting the data; straight into the table or via a form? I'm using a form. So, if you can use that, I'll walk you through it.

Comment: Normally you don't need to store any additional customer data in the activity table unless you want to save historical data. Actual customer information should be pulled from the Customer table using queries when you need it. Consider changing tables structure

Comment: At first I used form but I am thinking of scrapping it since it is easier to put the customer data straight into the table.

If I may correct my question, the activity is indeed more like a historical data with and customer name is necessary for easier management and contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a query to link the two tables together by Customer ID. However, if you want to display the name on a form that is bound to the Activity table, you can use a DLookup on a field.

=DLookup("CustomerName","CustomerTable","[CustomerID] = " & me.CustomerID)

Comment: Yes, I already linked the customer ID between the tables. Is it possible to "link" the name and the customer ID from both tables? so I can easily type the name then the customer ID auto-fills and vice versa. Perhaps one way that doesn't include form and just the tables. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If you want to see it on a datasheet, just use a query So if your Customer Table has CustomerID =1 and CustomerName = Jim. And Your Activity Table has CustomerID =1, you either do a join between CustomerID and drag CustomerName down as a field on the query. If you don't have the Customer Table you can do =DLookup("CustomerName","Customer","Customer.CustomerID = " & [Activitiy].[CustomerID])